# Set the datetime style in ultragrid

Tags: .net, vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a column with a `datetime` picker in ultragrid. Now i have to set the `minvalue` and `maxvalue` for that `datetime`.

//Code

```
            UltraGridColumn.Header.Caption = "Start Date"
            UltraGridColumn.Header.ToolTipText = "Start Date"
            UltraGridColumn.Hidden = True
            UltraGridColumn.Style = ColumnStyle.DateTimeWithSpin
```

I tried like minvalue as today and max value as 1 year from today. But not working

//Code

```
UltraGridColumn.MinValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day)
 UltraGridColumn.MaxValue = New DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year + 1, DateTime.Now.Month,DateTime.Now.Day)
```

Comment: You set two times the MinValue property. Is it a typo or is this your problem?

Comment: Even now i'm not getting the answeer

Comment: @Jonathan: Can u help me in this?

Comment: When you say 'not working' what is exactly that doesn't work. You can set values lower or bigger that set values or something else?

Comment: The minvalue and max value is not getting set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the MinValue property on the column itself:

```vb
' Put min and max constraints on a date column.
dateColumn.MinValue = New DateTime(1990, 1, 1)
dateColumn.MaxValue = New DateTime(2010, 12, 31)
```

Link to [MinValue documentation](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2012.2/CLR4.0/html/Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v12.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~MinValue.html).

Comment: if i have to set the min date as today and maxdate as today+1yr?

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddYear(1) will give you a year from now, and given that you should be able to work out how to get the date/time for now.